# Binary Search and using SortKey for two arrays - Very detailed [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, binary, key

I am making a program that reads a text file that looks like this:

```
  3679        87
   196        60
 17914        12
 18618        64
  2370        65
   584        85
 18524        34
 12024         5
  6992        76
 18410        56
```

So the list is set up like this, the left column is an item ID, and the right column is the number of the item in inventory(as if this were a store). What I need this program to do is,  sort the left column(Item ID's) from lowest to highest, then Print the list out like shown and have the correct amount of inventory aligned with it. So that it looks like this:

```
    184       14
    196       60
    206       31
    584       85
    768       85
    2370      65
    3433      5
    3679      87

    etc....
```

So what I have written so far by myself is, I import the file, split the numbers into two different arrays, so that I could sort the ID's using Arrays.sort().

Now what i'm trying to do is, make sure that if I sort the ID's I can have the inventory follow its assigned ID. I have done some searching on the Java Docs and found the SortKey function and I was wondering how I would use it? Or if it is even the right way to go about this.

Here is my current code:

```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Store {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // **************Scanner s = new
    // Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");

    ArrayList<String> numbersString = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> inventory = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int arraySize = numbersString.size();

    List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("file50.txt"));

    try {

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            l1.add(s.nextInt());
            l2.add(s.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.print(l1);
         System.out.println();
        System.out.print(l2);

        int[] list1 = new int[l1.size()];
        int[] list2 = new int[l2.size()];
        ArrayList<Integer> l3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int x = 0; x <= l1.size() - 1; x++) {

            int n = l1.get(x);
            list1[x] = n;

        }
        // System.out.print(Arrays.toString(list1));
        for (int p = 0; p <= l2.size() - 1; p++) {

            int o = l2.get(p);
            list2[p] = o;

        }
        for(int y = 0; y < l1.size(); y++){


        }

        Arrays.sort(list1);
        Arrays.sort(list2);
        //System.out.println();
        //System.out.print(Arrays.toString(list1));

    }

    catch (Exception i) {

        i.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
     }
```

I hope I made enough sense and it would be great for any suggestions for how to do what i'm trying to do!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lends itself to map. (Key Value store in java) 
Use a TreeMap (provides natural ordering on keys automatically), so you need not implement sorting at all.
Your task would be to just populate your treemap with file values.

Comment: Okay, so how would I get the ID's to sort from lowest ID to highest if you say the TreeMap will NOT sort?

Comment: TreeMap will automatically keep your keys in order (with corresponding values mapped properly). Your task is to just read the file line by line and populate the TreeMap with ID as key and inventory as value. Once TreeMap is populated you can just iterate and print to confirm that the values are sorted

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Gonna go do this! Seems like what i'm looking for. Again, thanks

Comment: Happy to be of help. A number of tutorials/examples are available on web. Check them out if you face issues in implementation.

Comment: One quick question. Which one should I use:   TreeMap customSortingMap = new TreeMap(Comparator comparator)                 or,              TreeMap naturalOrderMap = new TreeMap();

Comment: You should use a naturalOrderMap. Custom Comparators are required in case you were adding user defined objects. Java internally defines a natural ordering for integers.